Amazon Opensearch data nodes load balancing
Hi I had three master nodes and 11 data nodes in AWS Opensearch cluster. Yesterday I increased the number of data nodes to 12 but the search request to the new node is 0. It's CPU utilisation is also 0. What went wrong here?

How many indexes do you have, and how many shards and replicas do you have these indices? Maybe no shard moved to the new node!
